# How to reduce opencart page load time?

Tags: opencart, page-load-time, sql-server-performance

My opencart products [page](http://www.eklavya.in/pitara/books) is taking too much time to load, I tried to optimize query and database but it didn't work for me. I tested my page from [pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/dDp3qW/www.eklavya.in/pitara/books) page test. It takes more than 15 sec. I query fetch more than 300 records this might be a reason, and it increases server cup usage, how do I solve this issue.

Comment: Have you heard about *opencart's category count removal extensions*?

Comment: Yes I just read on forum and disabled it and upload one extension for that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your page is loading all the 300 records, its very obvious that it'll take more time. So you can implement the **ajax loading** of products instead, you'll gain major performance benefit.

Further , as per the pingdom report , your site has **0 grade** for the : **Leverage browser caching** Please improve it. 
More details : http://gtmetrix.com/leverage-browser-caching.html

As per the **Request Analysis and Size Analysis** of your site, image influence is too much. You have to consider the improvements for the images as well.

There is one **Free Module** in opencart **to speed up the site**, if it's compatible with your opencart version then you can try it.

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=13580

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found exact problem and it's solution. on open cart forum its about  category count removal. thanks again for help.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=126401#p500735) I found the solution

Disable product counts in Admin as

> System -> Settings -> Edit -> Option -> Category Product Count

. Then install this mod: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route ... n_id=10999